# How to find all elements in vector that are greater than certain number?

Tags: c++

So lets say I have some Class.

```
Class Example
{
int amount;
string name;
}
//constructors
...........
.....
int geAmount()
{
return amount;
}
```

And I create vector of objects.

```
Vector <Example> vector1;
```

How to find all elements where amount is greater than
 20(for example)?
I want to print them..

For example I have 3 objects.

```
Name=abc amount 5
Name=bcd amount 25
Name=dcg amount 45
```

So I want to print only the last two objects.

Comment: Every element in the vector will have a `amount` that is greater than, less than or equal to 20.

Comment: What exactly do you expect as the output? A new vector containing only the elements where amount is greater than 20, as set of indices, ...?

Comment: @NathanOliver, looks like OP wants to find elements that are greater than `20(for example)`. Hard to find those, I assume.

Comment: [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is your friend.

Comment: @SergeyA Orrignally they had *How to find all elements where amount is Greater/less/eqal to 20*

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, I mean one  of this cases.

Comment: @RSahu Or maybe `std::count_if`. Indices would be somewhat harder, if that’s what is wanted.

Comment: BTW, the `name` as an `int` only allows numeric values.  Maybe you want `std::string name;` instead?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a loop and access the `amount` member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Record
{
  int amount;
  std::string name;
};

static const Record database[] =
{
  {  5, "Padme"},
  {100, "Luke"},
  { 15, "Han"},
  { 50, "Anakin"},
};
const size_t database_size =
    sizeof(database) / sizeof(database[0]);

int main()
{
    std::vector<Record> vector1;

    // Load the vector from the test data.
    for (size_t index = 0; index < database_size; ++index)
    {
        vector1.push_back(database[index]);
    }

    const int key_amount = 20;
    const size_t quantity = vector1.size();
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < quantity; ++i)
    {
      const int amount = vector1[i].amount;
      if (amount > key_amount)
      {
        std::cout << "Found at [" << i << "]: "
                  << amount << ", "
                  << vector1[i].name
                  << "\n";
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ ./main.exe
Found at [1]: 100, Luke
Found at [3]: 50, Anakin
```

Comment: Corrected per @NathanOliver, changed type of `i` to `size_t`.

Comment: Why I need another vector results? Can I use only vector1?

Comment: The member `amount` is inaccessible because the default visibility of members of a `class` is private.  If you specific `public:` before the members, they can be accessed; or change the `class` to `struct`.

Comment: The `results` vector contains all the values greater than `key_amount`.  The vector `results` is not required.

Comment: Can you explain me this particular lines: const size_t quantity = st.size();
 for (size_t i = 0U; i < quantity; ++i)

Comment: What is `st`?  Use your favorite reference and find all the methods of `std::vector`, especially the [`size` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size).

Comment: I will read it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: See my latest edit.  I have changed the code to a working sample and included the output.

Comment: What is the difference between your method and method with iterator?

Comment: The difference is how the member is accessed.  With an iterator, you would need to dereference the iterator to access the `amount` member.